# How to make the value of an object property a searchable from an input tag

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have this api I am working from, I would like to make the country (i.e value.slug == china) to be a search item by the user no as I manually type them in the code to get the result of each country.

I want to be able to connect the api with my html form input tag for a user to search for the country themselves.

Here is the code

```
fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            let country = data.Countries.filter((value) => value.Slug == 'china')
            appendData(country);

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: First step would be replacing hardcoded value with a variable and wrapping fetch in function, next thing is attaching an event to an input which would call mentioned function. Now the question is are you using pure javascript or some framework as the latter can make work much easier?

Comment: Yes am using pure javascript, no framework @Jozef Podlecki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure javascript you can do the following:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#input")
input.addEventListener("change", function(event) { // enter key triggers event
   var value = event.target.value;
   console.log(value);
   getData(value);
});

function appendData(data) {
  // stub
  console.log(data);
}

function getData(country) {
fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            let country = data.Countries.filter((value) => value.Slug == country)
            appendData(country);

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```